# This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play (in live application)

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, revenuecat

When I tried to purchase a product with the in-app purchase I am receiving an error as mentioned below instead of in-app purchase dialog

```
This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play
```

Yes, there are lots of answers available online but they all suggested adding this particular user as a licensed tester, I am facing this issue in the live application and I can not add a user as a licensed tester.

I also find a workaround for this issue as mentioned below,

1. Uninstall the app from the device
2. I removed the google account from the device on which I am facing the issue
3. Then add a new google account on the same device
4. Install the app again from the google play store
5. And try to purchase a product and it worked
6. Again I uninstall the app
7. I remove the new google account from the device and add the old one
8. Install the app from the play store
9. And try to purchase a product and its shows the error mentioned above

Yes, adding a new google account fix the issue but my question is why this is not working with my existing google account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed

The live build did not contain the permission `com.android.vending.BILLING`

What I was doing wrong is, I added this permission to the build and was testing in debug mode and not from the internal testing of the google play console.

After adding this permission I uploaded the build to internal testing and download the app from there on my real device and everything worked as expected.

Still, the confusing point is in some android device billing works without the above-mentioned permission

Comment: Some older devices work without the permission as they werent as advanced as they are now to ask you for every small permission. Before, play store never used to show whether there are in-app-purchases or not. But, not it does all thanks to the permission